# Does Android support RTP/AVP/TCP?

Tags: android, rtsp, rtp

I am writing a RTSP client in Android for streaming video using Android SDK. For connecting  to RTSP server Android client sends RTP/AVP/UDP as transport option in SETUP command  so UDP is used for transport. But I want to use TCP for transport. What should  I do so that client will send RTP/AVP/TCP instead of RTP/AVP/UDP? Does Android support TCP transport for RTSP streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When streaming to an Android device using RTSP/RTP, the RTP portion MUST flow over UDP. Android does not support RTSP/RTP interleaved (RTP over TCP)

Most Android devices support RTSP/RTP streaming. Newer Android devices that are running version 2.2 or greater (Froyo) also support Flash player 10.1 and can play RTMP and Flash HTTP streams. Android devices cannot play MP3 streams over RTSP/RTP in any combination (audio/video or audio only). Android devices that support Flash player 10.1 can play MP3 using RTMP or Flash HTTP.

Comment: This answer appears to confuse `RTP/AVP/TCP;interleaved=0-1` with `RTP/AVP/TCP`. The latter is simple, it just sends RTSP over one TCP port and RTP over another TCP port (instead of one TCP/one UDP).